# Query on how to Select Date before the latest Date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need help on mysql query with regards to date.

I want to select the date before the latest date in mysql query. For example the dates are:

2013-01-29,
2013-02-28,
2013-03-29

The output must be 2013-02-28.

What sql clause must be used to return the said output?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried anything?

```
select yourDate from yourTable order by str_to_date(yourDate, '%Y/%m/%d') desc limit 2, 1
```

if you want to avoid duplicates, add `group by yourDate` clause before the order, and limit will be `1,1` instead of `2,1`

**edit**

As the field is a varchar, and you want to order as a date and not as a varchar, you need to cast the field in the order by

Comment: @Gonzalo. Sir I have tried your suggestion but the output was the latest date.

Comment: the field is date or varchar?

Comment: well, that's the problem. If is a varchar it acts like a string, so it  isn't the same order as a date. You need to cast the field as a date. Let me edit the query

Comment: @Gonzalo. Sir How can I cast the string to date. What sql clause will I use?

Comment: I've edited the query with the cast! See the diference in the order by clause

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MAX( date )
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE date < ( SELECT MAX( date )
                 FROM TABLE )
```

**[Sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5924e/2)**

Comment: Sir I got confused with the details. What's that for?

Comment: TO get the second latest date. Subquery returns the latest date to the main query and we find a date that is less than the latest date. check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5924e/2

Comment: Can I use the column date on the where clause. I mean like substituting 'date' to 'details' column?

Comment: Sir I have already tried that query. But the output was the latest date.

Comment: @Jessa: NOPE! You can see the live demo in the above comment. Let me know what do you exactly want.

Comment: @ArunKumarM. I've already seen the output on the live demo. It works perfect, but in my case I've used varchar datatype for date column, maybe it's the reason why it returns to the latest date. Do I have to cast the string to Date?

Comment: It works perfect on sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5daa/1 but it returns the latest date on the query browser i am using. What must be the problem?

Comment: can you post the query and table schema ?

Comment: SELECT MAX( date_updated)
  FROM tblpm
 WHERE control_number='YMF 111' and date_updated < ( SELECT MAX( date_updated)
                 FROM tblpm )

Comment: Guess its because of control_number = 'YMF 111'. Try to remove and check for the solution.

Comment: In sqlfiddle it works fine sir even though I put that control_number in the where clause.